# Confidence intervals from bootstrapping in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, bootstrap

If I am using Efron bootstrapping in order to get the optimism of several metrics of my model, I need to calculate a new model on a bootstrapped sample, then use it on the bootstrapped sample AND on the original sample. With this I am able to calculate the optimism. However, if I want the confidence interval (CI) of my metrics, let's say the AUC, from which samples should the CI be calculated ? Or should I not calculate it at all from this method ? I mean, is it from the distribution of AUC values from the bootstrapped models used on the bootstrapped sample, OR the original data ?